# Thomas Ordowski conjecture at OEIS sequence A007097

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

There is a conjecture that I found interesting concerning the prime numbers, and my question is to find a proof or a disproof of it. That conjecture was given by Thomas Ordowski at OEIS sequence A007097, you can see it at the following link
https://oeis.org/A007097

The conjecture is as follows: let $a(n)$ denote the "primeth recurrence" defined by $a(n+1)$ is the $a(n)$-th prime (with initial condition $a(0)=1$); then $\log(a(1)) \log(a(2)) \cdots \log(a(n)) \sim a(n)$.

Notification: before this bounty, when I asked this question in April 2020, the member "GH from MO" made a false disproof claim of the conjecture which appeared later to be a false disproof claim. And because of that I started this bounty.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you will get a better response if you make the question self-contained.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker thank you for advice, I will do it as soon as possible.

Comment: @GH from MO: I’m sorry but (I saw this from the followup on MSE) I can’t see the contradiction. Why *can’t* $\log{a_n}$ and $\log{a_{n-1}}$ be equivalent?

Comment: @Mindlack: You are right, I don't know what I was thinking! In fact $a(n)\sim a(n-1)\log a(n-1)$ implies that $\log a(n)\sim\log a(n-1)$.

Comment: @AhmadJamilAhmadMasad: My argument was incorrect (see the previous remark), so please remove "This conjecture was disproved, see the MathOverflow link" under https://oeis.org/A007097 Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GH from MO I will do that as soon as possible.

Comment: @GH from MO, Done. The comment was removed.